# Rails action runs with status 200 but template not accessed and jQuery not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

In the following code, "$('#movesindexrowstable').DataTable({..." never fires.  "$('#movesindexlotstable').DataTable({..." works perfectly, however.

Interestingly, the controller "moves" action "indexrows" renders with status 200, but the template isn't executed as breakpoints within it don't fire.  Of course, if the template isn't executed, then the ID movesindexrowstable is not processed which explains why the jQuery code doesn't fire.

The rendering code MovesIndexlotsDatatable and MovesIndexrowsDatatable return valid JSON.  Of course, even if it didn't, that should not impact rendering's use of the template?

Thinking that turbolinks may be involved, I changed the first line to use page:change instead of the common "$(document).ready(function () {" to conform to its requirements.  That didn't help and neither did adding data-no-turbolinks.

I am using DataTables and AJAX through jquery-datatables-rails to display the JSON data within the table.  However, DataTables never gains control because the selector is never recognized and the function does not fire.

This has me puzzled and I'd appreciate any assistance.  Thanks.

**EDIT:** I believe the following picture isolates the problem if not the solution.  The initial GET for Moves#Indexlots renders the template and the subsequent POST provides the data and renders no template.  My coding so far only includes the POST of the data for Moves#Indexrows.  It seems that I need to convince that POST to render the templates, or find an alternative way of doing so such as through a GET?  If so, I'd like recommendations on how to do that.  Thanks.

**EDIT:** Looking like the/an answer? [Render an HTML partial inside a JSON request](https://coderwall.com/p/ov8eha/render-an-html-partial-inside-a-json-request)
[image]

**EDIT:** In JQ, I changed "$.post('/moves_indexrows.json'" to "$.post('/moves_indexrows.html'.  This caused the POST to render the expected page.  The Network trace shows a page size of 15.6KB.  The Rails trace shows the ERB files that were rendered.  **Even thought the Browser saw all of this, no page change occurs!**  I really don't understand this.  Displays are:

[image: Network Trace shows 15.6KB page status 200, no change in view.]

[image: Rails Trace shows all ERB files/partials rendered, no view update.]

jQuery/JavaScript code:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){

  // AJAX DataTable Moves Lots for bulk moves
  var lots_active = [];
  var movesindexlotstable = $('#movesindexlotstable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    pagingType: 'full',
    jQueryUI: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'moves_indexlots.json',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      }
    },
    columns: [
      {"data": "name", className: null}
    ],
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {
      if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, lots_active) !== -1) {
        $(row).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
  $('#movesindexlotstable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, lots_active);
    if (index === -1) {
      lots_active.push(id);
    } else {
      lots_active.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  // Ajax moves, select lots
  $('#movesindexlotsbutton').on('click', function () {
    var source = 'lots';
    $.post('/moves_indexrows.json',
        {
          commit: 'Moves Lots',
          source: source,
          active: lots_active
        }
    );
    return false;
  });

  // AJAX DataTable Moves Rows within Lots for bulk moves
  var rows_active = [];
  var movesindexrowstable = $('#movesindexrowstable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    pagingType: 'full',
    jQueryUI: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'moves_indexrows.json',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      }
    },
    columns: [
      {"data": "name", className: null}
    ],
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {
      if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, rows_active) !== -1) {
        $(row).addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
  $('#movesindexrowstable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, rows_active);
    if (index === -1) {
      rows_active.push(id);
    } else {
      rows_active.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  // Ajax moves, select rows from selected lots
  $('#movesindexrowsbutton').on('click', function () {
    var source = 'rows';
    $.post('/moves_indexcars.json',
        {
          commit: 'Moves Rows',
          source: source,
          active: rows_active
        }
    );
    return false;
  });

});
```

RoR code:

```
class MovesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :check_if_associate

  def indexlots
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: MovesIndexlotsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end

  def indexrows
    lots  = Array.new
    params[:active].map { |lot| id = lot[4..(lot.length-1)].to_i; lots << Lot.find(id); }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: MovesIndexrowsDatatable.new(view_context, lots) }
    end
  end

end
```

moves/indexlots.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'indexlots', layout: 'layouts/kac_label', locals: {title: 'Moves Cars - Lots' } %>
</div>
```

moves/indexrows.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'indexrows', layout: 'layouts/kac_label', locals: { title: 'Moves Cars - Rows' } %>
</div>
```

moves/_indexlots.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group span8">
  <table id="movesindexlotstable" class="display dt-responsive no-wrap table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all"><b>Lot</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class='break_line'></div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Select Lots" id="movesindexlotsbutton" class="btn btn-primary kc-wide" data-no-turbolink data-disable-with="Processing">
  <%= link_to 'Home', '/', class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
</div>
```

moves/_indexrows.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group span8">
  <table id="movesindexrowstable" class="display dt-responsive no-wrap table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all"><b>Rows</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class='break_line'></div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Select Rows" id="movesindexrowsbutton" class="btn btn-primary kc-wide" data-no-turbolink data-disable-with="Processing">
  <%= link_to 'Home', '/', class: 'btn btn-primary kc-wide' %>
</div>
```

Logs:

```
...
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 127.0.0.1:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/moves_indexlots" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-20 16:58:32 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by MovesController#indexlots as HTML
  Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Associate Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "associates".* FROM "associates" WHERE "associates"."company_id" = $1 AND "associates"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 74]]
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "associates_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "associates_roles"."role_id" WHERE "associates_roles"."associate_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'associate') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["associate_id", 74]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Rendered moves/_indexlots.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered moves/indexlots.html.erb within layouts/application (17.5ms)
Action#Controller is indexlots#moves
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "associates_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "associates_roles"."role_id" WHERE "associates_roles"."associate_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["associate_id", 74]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (12.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (15.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2386ms (Views: 2103.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)


Started POST "/moves_indexlots.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-20 16:58:35 -0500
Processing by MovesController#indexlots as JSON
  Parameters: {"draw"=>1, "columns"=>[{"data"=>"name", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>true, "orderable"=>true, "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>false}}], "order"=>[{"column"=>0, "dir"=>"asc"}], "start"=>0, "length"=>10, "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>false}, "move"=>{"draw"=>1, "columns"=>[{"data"=>"name", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>true, "orderable"=>true, "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>false}}], "order"=>[{"column"=>0, "dir"=>"asc"}], "start"=>0, "length"=>10, "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>false}}}
  Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Company Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Associate Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "associates".* FROM "associates" WHERE "associates"."company_id" = $1 AND "associates"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 74]]
  Role Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "associates_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "associates_roles"."role_id" WHERE "associates_roles"."associate_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'associate') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["associate_id", 74]]
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 1]]
  Lot Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "lots".* FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."company_id" = $1  ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0  [["company_id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 195ms (Views: 52.5ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)


Started POST "/moves_indexrows.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-20 16:58:41 -0500
Processing by MovesController#indexrows as JSON
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Moves Lots", "source"=>"lots", "active"=>["Row_64", "Row_29"]}
  Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."prefix" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["prefix", "ucf"]]
  Associate Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "associates".* FROM "associates" WHERE "associates"."company_id" = $1 AND "associates"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 74]]
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "associates_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "associates_roles"."role_id" WHERE "associates_roles"."associate_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'associate') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["associate_id", 74]]
  Lot Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "lots".* FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."company_id" = $1 AND "lots"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 64]]
  Lot Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "lots".* FROM "lots" WHERE "lots"."company_id" = $1 AND "lots"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 1], ["id", 29]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 1]]
  Row Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "rows".* FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND (lot_id = 64)  ORDER BY name asc  [["company_id", 1]]
  Row Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "rows".* FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND (lot_id = 29)  ORDER BY name asc  [["company_id", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND "rows"."id" IN (186, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144)  [["company_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "rows".* FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND (lot_id = 64)  ORDER BY name asc  [["company_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "rows".* FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND (lot_id = 29)  ORDER BY name asc  [["company_id", 1]]
  Row Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "rows".* FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND "rows"."id" IN (186, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0  [["company_id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "rows" WHERE "rows"."company_id" = $1 AND "rows"."id" IN (186, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144)  [["company_id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 213ms (Views: 86.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
```

MovesIndexlotsDatatable JSON:

```
"{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[{"DT_RowId":"Row_64","name":"auction"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_29","name":"Buying-Ctr"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_30","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider A-H"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_27","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider B-G"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_31","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider C-F"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_32","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider D-E"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_36","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider E-L"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_35","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider F-K"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_34","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider G-J"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_33","name":"Buying-Ctr-Corrider H-I"}]}"
```

MovesIndexrowsDatatable JSON:

```
"{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":92,"recordsFiltered":14,"data":[{"DT_RowId":"Row_133","name":" A"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_134","name":" B"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_135","name":" C"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_136","name":" D"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_137","name":" E"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_138","name":" F"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_139","name":" G"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_140","name":" H"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_141","name":" I"},{"DT_RowId":"Row_142","name":" J"}]}"
```

Comment: This question is getting very complex.  I am going to ask a more direct, much simpler question given my current status to see if I get a response.  I'm not going to close this as of yet, in case someone can still help me and needs a lot of information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL/DR: Converted to using JavaScript as an SPA and Rails as an HTML/Data microservice.

The basic problem seems to be that Rails is not fully aware and comfortable with an action when that action is initiated from JavaScript.  It will run and will render with HTTP 200, but the render just does not display.  I ran the traces, comparing a standard action to one initiated by JavaScript and could not find a difference in processing.  I **assume** that there is some internal variable normally set at initiation, and not set via JavaScript, that causes this problem.  But, I did not find it.

I did, however, solve the problem.  Basically I turned this process into an SPA (Single Page Application).  The first action is standard Rails but it hands off to JavaScript on the User's first interaction or button click.  From then on, JavaScript runs the process, using AJAX POST to query Rails for HTML in one action and data in another, and thus consuming it as a micro-service.  JavaScript then renders the resultant page, waits for another click, and proceeds.  The last page provides buttons to again revert back to Rails standard processing.

That's my story and I'm sticking to it.  Thanks.

PS. I should mention that, in a one-off situation, firing an action with JS kind of worked for me.  My issue was the need to go through several layers of screens firing each through JS because I had information to pass back from JS to the action each time.  In a one-off situation, I just had the action send back control using:

```
render js: "window.location.assign(location.origin + '/item')" unless performed?
```